# LINQ optimization using single query on collection of integers

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of integers as below

`List<int> myCollection = new List<int> { 2625 };`

I am checking  below condition

```html
if(myCollection.Count() == 1 && myCollection.Any(number=> number == 2625))
{
        // Do something
}
```

How can I optimize my query so that I can include both conditions single query?
Note: MyCollection may contain multiple elements hence I have used Any().

Comment: Would be better in [CodeReview.SE] at least?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One obvious optimization would be to use `List` instance properties:

```
if(myCollection.Count == 1 && myCollection[0] == 2625))
{
        // Do something
}
```

Comment: myCollection can contain multiple elements hence can not use ` myCollection[0]` and '2625' can be present at any index

Comment: the second condition is checked only when the list has just 1 element

Answer (score 1):

Actually, here you have one query. Not two. Since your collection is a list, `Count()` will be resolved to `Count` property of list. That being said, nothing actually will happen here

```
myCollection.Count() == 1
```

except from getting the value of `Count`.

The only query happens here

```
myCollection.Any(number=> number == 2625)
```

Furthermore, since the first condition you check if the `Count` is 1, if it doesn't, then `Any` wouldn't be evaluated at all. (This happens because we make use of `&&`).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you want to
Optimize this, but if there is a single element why use .Any().

You could simply do

```
if(myCollection.Count() == 1 && myCollection.Single() == 2625)
 {
        // Do something
 }
```